# Why can't we generate electric current using thermal noise and diodes?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, perpetual-motion

Would it be possible to generate electric current just by placing diodes in a circuit? All realistic circuits have some thermal noise (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise). Since diodes only permit current to flow in one direction, why can't we just put some diodes in a circuit and expect to get "free" electricity?

Essentially, thermal noise is more or less the motion of electrons through the wire. Why not force them to only move one direction, and get "free" energy?

Comment: Wouldn't that also work with air molecules and a one-way valve or ratchet? Seems no different from any other good old Perpetuum Mobile.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I'm not actually saying this is possible. I know it's not possible to generate more power than you use here.

This question came from a discussion I had with a perpetual motion believer. I know enough to debunk most forms of perpetual motion nonsense, but I don't know enough about diodes and thermal noise to specficially say why this wouldn't work.

So basically, I'm looking for the reasons why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Sounds like a version of Maxwell's demon. I don't think this is possible because the thermal noise you speak of has too much entropy, or in other words too much randomness in direction. You want current in a particular direction, but statistically most of the random fluctuations are in all other directions, so you're never gonna get a useful amount of current/energy out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar in principle to a [Brownian ratchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_ratchet). The naïve expectation that this gives net energy output is based on an "ideal diode" that only allows current through in one direction, just as a Brownian ratchet is based on an "ideal pawl" that only allows motion through in one direction.

The resolution here is the same- if the diode is at the same temperature as the rest of the circuit, it has its own noise and is equally likely to pass current in the forward direction as the backwards direction.

If the diode is *not* at the same temperature as the rest of the circuit, then you *can* extract some energy from the thermal noise. But there's nothing wrong with that- there are two reservoirs at different temperatures and it becomes just a fancy heat engine.

Answer (score -2):

Diodes in reality are much more complicated than just "only permitting current in one direction", even the simplest models for diodes need around 0.7V potential across it to conduct; that is far beyond thermal potential.

Also, even if that weren't the case, and we had a super ideal diode that was a 'switch'; noise signals only cary power when you already have a signal bandwidth carrying some power (the noise signal power is not simply the thermal energy present in the circuit). This is clearly stated in the Wikipedia page you linked by the relation:

$$P_{\text{Noise}}=k_{\text{B}}\,T\Delta f$$

Where $\Delta f$ is the bandwidth.

Comment: If you have the "super ideal" diode you describe then you do get power, which depends on how large your bandwidth is. There is no contradiction here because the "super diode" you describe is necessarily at absolute zero.